# NumberFormat parse method returns negative result!

Tags: java, macos, formatting

I'm trying to format a String value to a valid currency double as follows

```
NumberFormat currency=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
currency.parse("10").doublevalue();
```

The problem is that I got back a negative number I got -10!. So is there any thing wrong with this code?

Thanks

Comment: I get `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "10"` I agree, it is strange. I have to add a currency symbol "£" for it to work.

Comment: what is your locale? Is this the actual code (it doesn't compile due to mistaken case)

Comment: post your currency type:`System.out.println(currency.getCurrency());`

Comment: post your print statement too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the role of NumberFormat a little bit.

You can simply call:

```
   double d= Double.parseDouble("10");
   NumberFormat currency=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
   System.out.println(currency.format(d));
```

For me, this prints out £10.00, and that's the string it would expect to be passed into the parse method

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try to use just

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("10");
```